# NoMethodError in Person#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

undefined method `people_path' for #<#:0x007f4be4bfbaa8>
Extracted source (around line #4):

```
<h1>Person#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/person/new.html.erb</p> 

<% form_for (@people) do |f|%>
<%= f.label :first_name%>
<%= f.text_field :first_name%>
<%= f.label :last_name%>
<%= f.text_field :last_name%>
<%= f.label :company%>
<%= f.text_field :company%>
<%= f.label :email%>
<%= f.text_field :email%>
<%= f.label :phone%>
<%= f.text_field :phone%>
<%end%>
```

---- Person Controller ----

```
  def new
    @people = Person.new
  end
```

I have an error when I call person/new

----routes-----
  get "person/new"
  get "person/index"
  get "person/show"
  get "person/delete"
  get "person/update"
  get "person/create"

resources :person

----migrate----
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
        t.string :first_name
        t.string :last_name
        t.string :company
        t.string :email
        t.string :phone
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

--model--
 
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: I don't see any `each` method called in the shared code. Please share the code where the concerned error is coming from.

Comment: I'm making an assumption, but what if you change `@people` to `@person`? Check your `people_controller.rb` file, under the `new` action to see what the object should be.

Comment: my controller is person_controller and in the new action there is this   def new
    @people = Person.new
end

Comment: Do you hace resources :persons in config.rb? Is there a def new end merhod in your personController ?

Comment: in this moment put "routes"

Comment: Silly question, Why did you name the variable as `@people` instead of `@person` ?

Comment: instead of @people i put person in controller and in views

Comment: Can you show us the 'Person' model as well?

Comment: ready. In this moment put it

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.rb`, your routes should be defined as below:

```
resources :people
```

This way `people_path` would be available.
After this, you can run `rake routes` and check the routes created for you as below:

```
people      GET    /people(.:format)                     people#index
            POST   /people(.:format)                            people#create
new_person  GET    /people/new(.:format)             people#new
edit_person GET    /people/:id/edit(.:format)       people#edit
person      GET    /people/:id(.:format)                 people#show
            PATCH  /people/:id(.:format)                        people#update
            PUT    /people/:id(.:format)                        people#update
            DELETE /people/:id(.:format)                        people#destroy
```

Comment: i can't to do it, i dont have a controller called people. I have a controller called person

Comment: You should rename your controller as `people`. As per rails convention if `Person` is your model then its plural form `People` should be the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
<% form_for (@people) do |f|%>
```

for this:

```
<% form_for url_for(controller: 'person', action: 'create', id: @people) do |f|%>
```

Comment: i did it but the fields weren't displayes and a did this <%= form_for(new_person_path) do |f| %> and show the fields, but better is put <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>