# undefined method `people_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f4bcc6bbbf0>:0x000000023b70c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

undefined method `people_path' for #<#:0x000000023b70c0>
Extracted source (around line #4):

## Person#new

Find me in app/views/person/new.html.erb

```
<% form_for (@person) do |f|%>
<%= f.label :first_name%>
<%= f.text_field :first_name%>
<%= f.label :last_name%>
```

controller-->

def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

routes-->

get "person/new"
  get "person/index"
  get "person/show"
  get "person/delete"
  get "person/update"
  get "person/create"

resources :person

Comment: Are you sure the routes output you've shown are all `get` verbs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoMethodError in Person#new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545950/nomethoderror-in-personnew)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Rails conventions your controller names must be **plural** versions of your model names.

**For example:**

- User / UsersController
- Message / MessagesController
- Contact / ContactsController
- ...

**And because the plural of "person" is "people":**

- Person / PeopleController

This convention is true even for singleton resources!

There are ways to override these conventions, but they are a hassle and take away much from the elegance of Rails routing. In general overriding conventions in Rails often produces "ripple effects" which force you to manually do stuff at other places, too.

In a nutshell: Make your life easy and use the following names:

- Model: `Person`
- Controller: `PeopleController`
- Route: `resources :people`

Answer (score 1):

Given your controller is `PeopleController`, update your route file as follows:

```
# config/routes.rb

# Use plural, i.e. people not person
resources :people
```

Comment: i called controller person

Comment: In that case, please see [Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources).  The note under the `routes` might be useful.

Comment: i have resources :person

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "person/new"
get "person/index"
get "person/show"
get "person/delete"
get "person/update"
get "person/create"

resources :person
```

According to the [Rails Routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), your setting of the routes manually is not in line with convention (RESTful routes). You're best using `resources :controller` only:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :person
```

This is taking into consideration that your controller is called `persons_controller.rb` (as you stated in your comments)